# Nextjs migrating from pages to app router giving 404 for few pages which are migrated

Tags: next.js, http-status-code-404, app-router

I recently migrated my web application from pages to app router incrementally with few pages moved to app router. But after successful migration and deployment i found out sometimes few of the pages give 404 after deployment and when i re re run my aws build than it starts working again properly. I have deleted that duplicate pages from pages router and still the issue is coming. Can anyone help what can be the root cause, not able to figure out. Nextjs v14.0.1.

I tried deleting cache of my cdn and also tried to reproduce the same on local but it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

It could be issue with how static and/or dynamic routes are configured in your application.

You need to check your code for `getStaticPaths` (pages router)/`generateStaticParams` (app router) and and its `fallback` (pages router) / `export const dynamicParams` (app router) values. Fallback controls how our app behave when unknown route is being requested by client.

> In the pages directory, the fallback property returned from
> getStaticPaths is used to define the behavior of a page that isn't
> pre-rendered at build time.
>
> This property can be set to true to show a
> fallback page while the page is being generated, false to show a 404
> page, or blocking to generate the page at request time. ... In the app directory the config.dynamicParams property controls how params outside of generateStaticParams are handled

Further read:

- https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/upgrading/app-router-migration#dynamic-paths-getstaticpaths
- https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/upgrading/app-router-migration#replacing-fallback

Do you know how you app is being deployed? The deployment config (i.e. output: export static or similar) can also influence the behavior of routing-related features, because they only render the pages on build time (static) as opposed to "runtime" (dynamic).

> Source: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/deploying/static-exports#unsupported-features
>
> Unsupported Features
>
> - Dynamic Routes with dynamicParams: true
> - Dynamic Routes without generateStaticParams()
> - Route Handlers that rely on Request
> - etc.

Comment: these 404 errors are coming on few static pages all dynamic pages are working fine.      showing you the code for the page which is giving 404 error                             

const fetchPageData = cache(async () => {
 const { isEnabled } = draftMode();
 const [data] = await Promise.all([
  cmsClient.get(cmsClient.API_LIST.makeoSkinnsiLhr, isEnabled),
 ]);

 return {
  props: {
   ...data,
   headerProps: {
    title: "laser hair reduction",
   },
   footerProps: {
    addBottomPaddingDesktop: true,
    
   },
  },
 };
});

export default LhrPage;